# How can I use an If-statement inside the Collector?

Tags: java, if-statement, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

The output I require is like this :

```
"Versions" : [("0.1","true"),("0.2","false"),("0.3","true")]
```

The structure of this output is: `Map<String, List<Pair<String, String>>>`

Where `"Versions"` is the key of the Map and `[("0.1","true"),("0.2","false"),("0.3","true")]` this is the value of the `Map`.

Now, inside the `Map` we have a `List` like: `List<Pair<String, String>>` eg is this : `[("0.1","true"),("0.2","false"),("0.3","true")]`

Where `"0.1","0.2","0.3"` is the key of the `Pair`  and `"true","false","true"` is the value of the `Pair`.

How do I write an `if-else` statement for this `Pair`? Where for a particular condition I want the value of the `Pair` to be returned as `true` or `false`?

Comment: You need to tell what you receive as an input, and also, please add the code that you have so far.

Comment: There's no `if` statements in your code. Can you specify what exactly needs to be compared? I.e. how to define that the value of a particular pair should be `true` or `false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the existing implementation of map entry by invoking the static method `Map.entry()` that expects a key and a value (*only for Java 9 and above*) or by invoking the constructor of map entry directly:

```
new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(key, value)
```

The attribute *key* is defined as `final` and *value* is mutable. If you are not satisfied with that (*for instance, if you need an immutable object*), you can define your own class `Pair`.

```
public class Pair<K, V> {
    private final K key;
    private final V value;
    
    public Pair(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    // getters
}
```

> How do I write an `if-else` statement for this `Pair`? Where for a particular condition I want the value of the `Pair` to be returned as `true` or `false`?

For your conditional logic (`if` *statements that you've mentioned*) you can either it in-line inside the collector (*as it shown below*) or extract it into a separate method, which will be a better option if there are several conditions.

The only change needs to be done to your code is to replace the string concatenation inside the `Collectors.mapping()` with the expression that creates a map entry (*or an instance of your custom class*) which take the concatenated string representing a version as a key and the result of the condition as a value.

```
Collectors.mapping(cae -> Map.entry(cae.getMajorVersion() + "." + cae.getMinorVersion(),
                                    String.valueOf(your_condition)), 
            Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method/Function which accepts a `CorporateActionEvent` and returns a `Pair<String, String>` :

```
public static Pair<String, String> getPair(CorporateActionEvent cae){
   boolean myCondition; //= check whatever
   String key = cae.getMajorVersion() + "." + cae.getMinorVersion();
   return new Pair(key, String.valueOf(myCondition));
}
```

and use it by adjusting the corresponding mapping

```
....Collectors.mapping(cae -> getPair(cae), Collectors.toList())));
```

or using method reference, assuming you placed the `getPair` method in your `CorporateActionEvent` class:

```
....Collectors.mapping(CorporateActionEvent::getPair, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: You forgot the conversion from `boolean` to `String`